# of the highest quality vs high quality

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Which sentence makes the most sense:

> ...produce the most sophisticated tool and of the highest quality to perform the job

or

> ...produce the most sophisticated and high quality tool to perform the job
>   ?

Basically I want to say that *we have the means to...*

I'm not a native English speaker and feel like both sentences make sense but I'm not sure about the use of **of the highest quality** vs just **high quality**. I'm also not so sure about **produce** vs **create**, I want it to sound formal.

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both fine in terms of usage. But here's something that you should ask yourself.

Is the product you're making the best? If nobody else can make the tool to the same standard, then you can use the term '**highest**'. If you just mean good quality and no defects, you should go with '**high**'.

The reason is that, first, the term **highest** is the superlative form of **high**. Second, it is like a marketing or promotional script so you're trying to speak good of your product.

As for the words produce and create, these are synonyms. Today, many people use words like assemble, build, create and manufacture to mean the same thing. But again, it comes down to the context where the words are used. Given the piece of script, either of your words sounds fine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which structure you use.

> `#1` . . . produce + **`[adjective phrases]`** + noun.

or

> `#2` . . . **`[produce + noun(s)]`** + and + **`[(produce) + noun(s)]`**.
>
> > - This means the parenthesized produce can be absent.

---

---

**Case#1: `2 adjective phrases`**

> . . . produce **[**`the` most sophisticated and `(the)` highest quality tool(s)**]** to perform the job.
>
> > - Since you already have an article **"the"** for the word **"most"**, an article **"the"** in the parentheses can be absent for the superlative adjective **"highest"**.

**Case#2: `The parenthesized produce`**

> . . . **[**`produce` the most sophisticated tool(s)**]** *and* **[**`(produce)` the highest quality tool(s)**]** to perform the job.
>
> > - Since you have the verb **"produce"** before the conjunction **"and"**, the verb **"produce"** in the parentheses can be absent for the second part.